# The music doesn't start

Tags: c++, class, audio, sfml

When i run the programm the music doesn't star.
I checked if the file is preloaded whitout problem .
My file is .ogg whih is supported by sfml.
I don't get why i have no sound when i run the program. 
There is no problem when i load the file

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

class Audio
{
public:
        Audio();
        ~Audio();
        bool    load();
        bool    gest();
private:
        sf::Music       _main;
};

bool    Audio::load()
{
    if (!_main.openFromFile("res/zelda.ogg"))
                return false;
        return true;
}

bool    Audio::gest()
{
        if (!load())
                return false;
        _main.play();
        return true;
}

int     main(void)
{
        Monitor         window;
        Audio           music;

        window.initWindow();
        while (window.run())
                music.gest();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `music.gest()` in a loop, which in turn *calls `load()` every time around!* You do call `sf::SoundStream::play()` in the loop as well, but the stream gets re-initialized every time.

You shouldn't call `play()` in a loop anyway. SFML makes sure the sf::Music instance keeps streaming on its own thread.